# How to Remap Chewing (Chinese Input Method)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-method

I'm using Bodhi Linux and yesterday made a huge mistake upon updating the system and remapped my keyboard completely wrong. I was able to get the English keyboard remapped, but the Chinese is still completely wrong.

I am using the Chewing input method as I live in Taiwan and it works best for me.

Also, I completely uninstalled Chewing and then reinstalled and rebooted but the problem wasn't solved.